# Is it possible to remove a user control (.ascx) present in master page (.master) from content (.aspx) page?

Tags: c#, .net, master-pages

I have a master page which is being inherited to a lot of content page. I have one particular page in which I do NOT want one of the user controls present in the master page. I do NOT want to create a separate master page for this. I want to know if there's any way to prevent the user control present in master page being inherited to child / content page. Appreciate your help. thanks !

In the user control,

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Css.Register(this, "/css/reset.css", BrowserTarget.All, true);
}
```

In the master page, the user control is added

The part (css in reset.css) I'm trying to remove / prevent being inherited to 
the content page

```
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the control to never exist at all with what you're saying and your feedback that hidden doesn't fit your needs, I'm guessing removing the control won't either.

The only other option here is to change the master page to have a flag that loads the control. This changes the approach from "remove this if" to "include this when." Then, in your calling pages, you'll need to set that flag. To make this new change less invasive, set the default the true and in this page set it to false.

Comment: Thank you. I agree, but would need to make change in a lot of content page. Better will create a separate master page

Comment: That's why I mentioned setting the default flag to the page to true. Then, you only need touch the pages that are the exception.

Comment: In the master page code behind (.master.cs), added the below

<!-- language: c# -->
    private string _lblName = null;

    public string lblName
    {
        get { return _lblName; }
        set { _lblName = value; }
    }


In the master page design (.master), added the below.
<!-- language: c# -->
' <% if (lblName != "true") { %>
            <uc3:RegisterCssJs ID="RegisterCssJs1" runat="server" />
        <% } else { %>
            
        <%} %>'

I'm setting the value of lblName to "true" in the content page where I do  NOT want the control to be inherited. But still it gets inherited.

Comment: What do you mean by getting inherited and how are you verifying this?

Comment: The css gets applied to the content page

Comment: And you're sure there's absolutely no other way the same CSS file is getting added? No other controls or base pages doing the registration?

Answer (score 1):

You can use in the child control:

```
((UserControl)this.Master.FindControl("userControlName")).Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not want to hide it. I want to completely remove it in the content page. I do not want that to be inherited

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    MasterPage master = this.Master;
    UserControl userControl = (UserControl)master.FindControl("userControlName");
    if(userControl != null)
{
    master.Controls.Remove(userControl );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't throw any error. But it still inherits the user control. In the page_init of the user control, there are some css registered. I'm trying to avoid that css being inherited. The above doesn't throw any error, but still the css gets registered.

Comment: Try removing the css class attribute from your user control like below                         `userControl.Attributes.Remove("class");  
userControl.Attributes.Add("class", "");`Edit your question and add your user control page_init code